# Legend in ggplotly doesnt display all the values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I have created the following dataframe

```
  ##### TOY SET 
  DF1<-data.frame("Sl_NO"= c(1:70))

 DF1$ID<-paste0("A_1234_2345_3456_4567_7777", as.character(DF1$Sl_NO))

  DF1$Value<-DF1$Sl_NO
```

Next I Create 2 more dataframes with the following changes

```
  DF2<-DF1
  DF2$Value<-DF1$Sl_NO*1.5
  DF3<-DF1
  DF3$Value<-DF3$Sl_NO*1.25
```

Next we rbind the dataframes

```
    DFmain<-rbind(DF1, DF2, DF3)
    library(ggplot2)
```

Create a plot with ggplot

```
     p<-ggplot(data = DFmain)+geom_line(aes(x = Sl_NO, y = Value, color=ID))
     p
     library(plotly)
     ggplotly(p, dynamicTicks = T)
```

When I run the plot, p runs and all the legend entries are visible. When I run the part with ggplotly, the legend appears as a scroll down but the number of legend items is less than the number of plotted lines.
Is there a way to ensure all the legend entries are visible. Request someone to help

Comment: I get `length(unique(DFmain$ID)) = 70` and I can see 70 items in the legend.

Comment: Are you visualizing the plot in RStudio ? I'm opening it in Chrome and no problem.

Comment: The RStudio viewer has many issues. It's better to open in a browser like Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get `length(unique(DFmain$ID)) = 70` and I can see 70 items in the legend. I visualize the plot in Chrome. Probably you get an issue because you visualize in RStudio. It's better to use a browser like Chrome.